# jQuery - select elements containing custom data

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, jquery-data, custom-data-attribute

I have a couple of elements like

```
<p data-lang-bg="Bulgarian" data-lang-en="English" >Text</p>
<p data-lang-bg="Other bulgarian text" data-lang-en="Other english text" >Text 2</p>
```

I have a difficulties writing a jQuery selector, that will select all elements, who have data attributes **starting** with data-lang . Is it possible to write such a jQuery selector

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe this is possible. I could see how it would be useful however, maybe file a report for this with the jQuery team.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You'd have to iterate over all elements and their datasets.

Comment: Really, this is what classes are good for. I would simply add `class="lang"` to each such element and select that instead.

Comment: I vote to reopen because this question is much more specific (it's about data, not any attribute) and thus can have better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the nearest I can propose.

Change your HTML to this structure :

```
<p data-lang='{"bg":"Bulgarian","en":"English"}' >Text</p>
```

Then use this selector :

```
$('[data-lang]')
```

For example, you can get your languages values as maps :

```
$('[data-lang]').each(function(){
    var localizations = $(this).data('lang'); // parses the map as JSON
    ... use the object, for example localizations['en']
});
```

This looks to me like the correct way to use the power of custom data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-list-attributes/

```
(function($) {
      // duck-punching to make attr() return a map
      var _old = $.fn.attr;
      $.fn.attr = function() {
          var a, aLength, attributes,   map;
          if (this[0] && arguments.length === 0) {
                    map = {};
                    attributes = this[0].attributes;
                    aLength = attributes.length;
                    for (a = 0; a < aLength; a++) {
                              map[attributes[a].name.toLowerCase()] = attributes[a].value;
                    }
                    return map;
          } else {
                    return _old.apply(this, arguments);
          }
}
}(jQuery));
```

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/retrieving-all-attributes-of-a-given-element-and-their-values

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':']['data-lang'] = function (obj) {
    var data = $(obj).data();
    for (i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (i.indexOf('lang') === 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then select them with `$('p:data-lang')`.

Comment: This doesn't work as is. You should use `$.expr[':']['data-lang'] = function...`.